# 3rd party libraries of Python cant be used on MSYS2 terminal, how to use them in MSYS2 terminal?

Tags: python, msys2

OS: windows 10

I install python3.9, pip install many 3rd party packages and use them well on both Pycharm and CMD terminal;

Later, I install MSYS2 and then I tpye 'python' on the terminal of MSYS2 and get into python terminal; it seems well until now. When I import sth, getting the warning "No module named 'xxx'" which can be imported well on Pycharm or CMD terminal.

so I guess the path of 3rd party packages not be included for MSYS2, how to resovle it?

Comment: Do you really want to use an external installation of Python from within MSYS2?  Would you accept an answer that helps you instead use the Python package that MSYS2 provides?

Comment: yes, I accept it; thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the standard way to use Python 3 and pip in MSYS2:

1. Select the "MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit" shortcut or run mingw64.exe to start a MinGW 64-bit shell.  (32-bit should work too.)
2. Run `pacman -S $MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX-{python3,python3-pip}` to install both Python 3 and pip.
3. Run `pip install PKGNAME` to install a package you need.
4. Run `python path/to/script.py` to run your script.

I tested these instructions just now.  I was able to run `pip install pyserial` and then I was able to run a script that started with `import serial`.

Comment: thanks, I hanve compled 1~2 as your described as above; then I `pip install numpy`, get the error as below: `Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly`

Comment: I think I've answered your original question, and now you have a much more specific question about this particular package which should be asked separately.